# How to disable field when type value equal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am having two form fields

- Property Type
- Bedroom

My requirement is Property Type **Plot/Site/Land** is checked means  Bedroom i want to make unchecked and disable suppose  **Plot/Site/Land** means again i want to do enable the bedroom field how can do this

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name=propertyType]").change(function() {
    var propertyType = $(this).val();
    if(propertyType == 7){
      $("input[name=unitType]").prop("disabled", true);
    }else{
      $("input[name=unitType]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Property Type :
<fieldset>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="4"> Apartment</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="7"> Plot/Site/Land</label>
</fieldset>

Bedroom:

<fieldset>
    <label><input value="1 Room/Hall" name="unitType" type="checkbox">1 Room/Hall</label>
    <label><input value="1 RK" name="unitType" type="checkbox">1 RK</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `myFunction is not defined` , what is the `myFunction` ?

Comment: You should consider interpunction...

Comment: That is because `var propertyType = $(this).val();` is returning a `string` and not a `number`. Use the unary opeartor to convert it to a number/integer before comparing, i.e.: `var propertyType = +$(this).val();`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in the change event of `value = "7"`, you need to change the selector to

```
var $value7 = $("input[name='propertyType'][value='7']");
$value7.change(function() {
  $("input[name='unitType']").prop( "disabled",  !$(this ).prop( "checked" ) );
});

$("input[name='unitType']").prop( "disabled",  !$value7.prop( "checked" ) );
```

And remove `myFunction` call from everywhere else.

**Demo**

```js
var $value7 = $("input[name='propertyType'][value='7']");
$value7.change(function() {
  $("input[name='unitType']").prop( "disabled",  !$(this ).prop( "checked" ) );
});

$("input[name='unitType']").prop( "disabled",  !$value7.prop( "checked" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Property Type :

<fieldset class="checkboxes">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="4"> Apartment</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="5"> Independent House/ Villa</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="6"> Individual House/ Standalone Building</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="7"> Plot/Site/Land</label>
</fieldset>


Bedroom:

<ul style="padding-left: 0px;">
  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="1 Room/Hall" name="unitType" type="checkbox">1 Room/Hall</label></li>
  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="1 RK" name="unitType" type="checkbox">1 RK</label></li>
  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="1 BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox">1 BHK</label></li>
  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="2 BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox">2 BHK</label></li>
  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="3 BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox">3 BHK</label></li>
  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="4 BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox">4 BHK</label></li>
  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="4+ BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox">4+ BHK</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code almost ok but not fully,if am clicking Plot/Site/Land means first i have to make uncheck and then disable but ur code uncheck is not happening

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `change` listener and target your Plot/Site/Land input. This should give you a nice start.

```js
$(function() {

  $("input[value='7']").change(function() {
    $("input[name=unitType]").prop("checked", false);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="5" onclick="myFunction()"> Independent House/ Villa</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="6" onclick="myFunction()"> Individual House/ Standalone Building</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="7" onclick="myFunction()"> Plot/Site/Land</label>
</fieldset>


Bedroom:

<ul style="padding-left: 0px;">

  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="1 Room/Hall" name="unitType" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">1 Room/Hall</label></li>


  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="1 RK" name="unitType" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">1 RK</label></li>


  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="1 BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">1 BHK</label></li>


  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="2 BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">2 BHK</label></li>


  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="3 BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">3 BHK</label></li>


  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="4 BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">4 BHK</label></li>


  <li class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;"><label class="space"><input value="4+ BHK" name="unitType" type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">4+ BHK</label></li>


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use a **radiobutton** instead

This is what a radiobutton is designed for. When given the same name, you can only select one:

```
<fieldset>
    <label><input type="radio" name="propertyType" value="4"> Apartment</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="propertyType" value="7"> Plot/Site/Land</label>
</fieldset>
```

This required no Javascript and users are familiar with radiobuttons so expected behaviour (you can choose one, a checkbox suggests multiple).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name=propertyType]").change(function() {
    var propertyType = $(this).val();
    if(propertyType == 7 && $(this). prop("checked")){
      $("input[name='propertyType'][value!='7']").prop("checked",false);
      $("input[name='unitType']").prop("checked",false);
      $("input[name=unitType]").prop("disabled", true);
    }else{
      $("input[name='propertyType'][value='7']").prop("checked",false);
      $("input[name=unitType]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Property Type :
<fieldset>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="4"> Apartment</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="propertyType" value="7"> Plot/Site/Land</label>
</fieldset>

Bedroom:

<fieldset>
    <label><input value="1 Room/Hall" name="unitType" type="checkbox">1 Room/Hall</label>
    <label><input value="1 RK" name="unitType" type="checkbox">1 RK</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Your code almost ok but not fully,if am clicking Plot/Site/Land means first i have to make uncheck and then disable but ur code uncheck is not happening

Comment: Now check.Is this OK?

Comment: ,Still uncheck is not ahppening

Comment: still propblem happening like suppose i am selecting property type is appartment then i am selecting Bedroom 1 Room/Hall again i am selection property type is Plot/Site/Land means Bedroom all values deselected and not able to select also fine but property type apparment i selected that also getting deselected , come to second issue again i am selecting property type appartment means apparment is getting selected as well as Plot/Site/Land getting deselected , should not come like this both should selected

Comment: just remove $("input[name='propertyType'][value='7']").prop("checked",false); from else part you will get desired outout

Comment: Again problem is happening bro like i am selecting property type is appartment then i am selecting Bedroom 1 Room/Hall again i am selection property type is Plot/Site/Land means Bedroom all values deselected and not able to select also upto now working fine but property type apparment i deselect means apparment getting deselected as well Plot/Site/Land also deselected but should not come like , actual results only apartment get deselect.